# fill in blank values based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

This should be simple, however I cant find a solution

Input dataframe

```
id      Y/N
1       
2       
50      
6       
70      Y
100     Y
```

I would like to fill in blanks using condition: if id>49 and Y/N is null then Y/N = Y, else leave Y/N

so the output is

```
id      Y/N
1       
2       
50      Y
6       
70      Y
100     Y
```

Comment: You sample output doesn't match the logic you provide. Why is `id  == 6` 'Y' ?

Comment: Thank you, fixed

Comment: Is this what you want `df.loc[(df['id']>49) & (df['Y/N"].isnull(), "Y/N"] = "No Data"`

Comment: I think OP edited the question but still, op asks for "No Data" but in their sample, they show "Y" and that's confusing.

Comment: I think OP is confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` for this case:

```
df['Y/N'] = np.where(df['Y/N'].isna() & df['id']>49,'Y',df['Y/N'])
```